# Set class by jQuery in sequence of divs

Tags: jquery, class, html

Colleagues, I have the divs:

```
<!-- question 0 -->
<div id="question 0">
<!-- stars -->
<div class="1 ratings_stars"></div>
<div class="2 ratings_stars"></div>
<div class="3 ratings_stars"></div>
<div class="4 ratings_stars"></div>
<div class="5 ratings_stars"></div>
<!-- text -->
<div class="question_text">
What do you think about us ?
</div>

</div>
```

I'm looking for smart jquery expression to set defined class to div "Question 0" in such way: I read values, for example, 3 from cookies and therefore I have to change the class in div 1, div 2, div 3. - this is rating for question.

I understand that I can write DOM-handling code to set it, but, may be, there is good cute solution in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the space in `id` is **forbidden**. Change it to a hyphen, `-` or underscore, `_`.

You can use the [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to reduce the selected set of stars:

```
var stars = 3; // From cookie?
var $div = $('#question-0');
$div.children('.rating_stars').slice(0, stars).addClass('rating-color');
```

Comment: @Eugene If you do not have/need an existing reference to the question div, you can use the child selector instead of the `.children()` method: `$('#question-0 > .rating_stars').slice(0, stars).addClass('rating-color');`.